# Change Get [app name] text on a Facebook post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, sharekit

I have integrated FB sharing using ShareKit 2.0 and I can share links from my application. However I need to know the possibility of modifying "Get [app name]" and domain eg.www.apple.com text displayed right after the post title. Will I be able to change these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your CustomSHKConfigurator.m override the following two methods:

```
- (NSString*)appName {
    return @"";
}

- (NSString*)appURL {
    return @"";
}
```